# extract data points for the plot

Tags: matlab

I want to extract data points of a plot, but this plot is in a .jpg format. I converted it to the .fig but there are two curves in this plot and I don’t know how to do it.
How can I extract data points for the plot that I attach here?
[image]

Comment: I believe that this will be flagged as it is too broad. It is an interesting question however. 
The method that you used to extract depend on your approach, I had done that cutting the edges (having only the "inside" of the graphic) and getting the line positions by pixel intensities on figure and attributing values using values given by me. Getting the numbers together, understanding the ticks and lines often are *AI methods*. The data is often easier to separate by hand. If you want a general method, often falls in AI again. Good luck :D !

Comment: Surely, the way you said was easier and faster, but I want to know if there is a possibility that MATLAB would accurately pinpoint the points. If I do not get the logical answer, this will be the solution. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: You might want to look at a popular File Exchange tools like GRABIT: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7173-grabit. However, in its current form this question is indeed too broad

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. But unfortunately, I didn't understand and couldn't use this tool.